# Elasticsearch DSL query returning result for condition which isn't true

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to have three conditions in my elasticsearch query and accordingly I have written as below. But I don't know why it is returning a DOCUMENT where AMOUNT is 250 and it EXISTS whereas my condition is ATLEAST one of the two i.e. AMOUNT less than or equal to zero or AMOUNT should not exist.

Below is the DSL Query
[image]

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":10,
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "_source": ["amount", "npa_stageid_loanaccounts"],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "query_string":{
                  "default_field":"npa_stageid_loanaccounts.keyword",
                  "query":"Y"
               }
            },
            {
               "bool":{
                  "minimum_should_match":1,
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "range":{
                           "Amount":{
                              "lte":0
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "bool":{
                           "must_not":[
                              {
                                 "exists":{
                                    "field":"Amount"
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your documents, you have `amount` but in your query you have `Amount`, the casing is not the same.